Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding `'use client'`
"use client"; 
import Index1 from "./index1";
const Demo = () => {return (<div><Index1 /></div>);};
export default Demo;

export default async function Index1() {
let res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
let repo = await res.json();
return (<div>
{repo && repo.map((user: any) => {user.name})}
</div>);}


Throwing Error in log async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding `'use client'` to a module that was originally written for the server.
Is there is any solution for this scenario ?


Any child of a client component will be treated as a client component.

This question is similar to: Nextjs: Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: How to import async Server Components into Client Components in Nextjs 13?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Are you trying to do a API fetch when the page is loading?
